# Not seeing syslogs when syslog server is added by its host name

Tags: syslog, syslog-ng

I have a Kiwi syslog server running on a PC,when i add the ip address of this sys log server to my device i'm able to see the syslogs on server side. If i add the host name of syslog server to syslog-ng.conf file of my device,i do not see my logs on the server side.

I added below command to syslog-ng.conf file

> destination df_remote_1 {udp("target_host");};
>
> log { source(s_all); filter(f_remote); destination(df_remote_1);};

I have also added entries for "/etc/reolv.conf" file which holds DNS config.

I'm able to ping the host name from my device,but i do not see the logs? Could someone please guide me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the messages reach the target host using tcpdump/wireshark. Maybe there is a firewall rule somewhere that blocks the packages.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a minute to review the site's [how to answer section](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this is a helpful suggestion, it doesn't explicitly answer the question and is probably better posted as a comment (in this case, the question itself IMO needs a little more info)